# kotlin and spring boot error in Intellij

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

I'm creating a `Kotlin` project with `Spring boot` and `Gradle` project from[start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io)

When importing this project to IntelliJ and run the project(Alt+Shift+F10) then show this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.demo.DemoApplicationKt
```

mainclass :

```
package com.example.demo

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please post DemoApplicationKt file

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Show your main class for starting spring boot

Comment: @SangeetSuresh edited

Comment: @SangeetSuresh Do you have any idea of creating a project with Kotlin and spring boot in IntelliJ?

Comment: Do you made any manipulations with example project from start.spring.io?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin yes I'd like to create a project Kotlin and spring boot by start.spring.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the application by clicking the **run button(play button)** which is on the left side of the main class as shown in below picture.

[image]

If you run like this, it will automatically create run configuration

Comment: when I do it shows this error ** Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.demo.DemoApplicationKt**

Comment: @MohammadDaliri Please post your run configuration if you have any

Comment: it's work fine. change direction source project to another folder and then run